# Start a Loop at the nth Entry in a Structure and Loop to the End?

Tags: structure, loop

I'm trying to start a loop at the 8th entry in a structure and then loop through the remaining entries in that structure and stop once I reach the end. How would I accomplish this in Craft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [offset](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#offset) parameter you can achieve this:

`{% for entry in craft.entries.section('structureSection').offset(8) %}`